# How to format my \chapter* similarly to my \chapter style

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I have used the following code to format my chapters and sections in my report.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dtured}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\definecolor{dtugray}{RGB}{153,153,153}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{\color{dtured}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Large}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{dtugray}}
{\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This has formatting}
\chapter*{This has not}
\end{document}
```

I now want to make the same style apply to the chapters i have made in the `\chapter*` environment, is this possible?

Comment: Can you please make your example compilable?

Comment: Yes, it should be done now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can formate the stared chapters with `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{...}{...}`. Of course you will have to change the following example, as `\thechapter` does not make sense for starred chapters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dtured}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\definecolor{dtugray}{RGB}{153,153,153}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{\color{dtured}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Large}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{dtugray}}
{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{\color{dtured}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Large}


\begin{document}
\chapter{This has formatting}
\chapter*{This has not}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dtured}{RGB}{153,0,0}
\definecolor{dtugray}{RGB}{153,153,153}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{\color{dtured}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Large}


\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{dtugray}}
{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\color{dtured}\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
{}{-25pt}{\huge}


\begin{document}

    \chapter{This has formatting}
    text
    \chapter*{Forord}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Forord}
    text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Im not sure if it's because i dont quite understand your solution, but i want to be able to still customize the name, so that i can make '\chapter*{SOMETHINE}' without it changing the format from my previous chapters. This is because i have som chapters named "Part" 1, 2,3 and so fourth. (renamed the chapters with a rennewed command line). But i dont see how this solution helps me, can you explain? :)

Comment: @MikkelMiqlliotLehmann Starred and normal chapters can be formatted completly independent. See the my edit with the blue colour for example. If this does not help, can you show in your question what you want the output to be like?

Comment: Okay, i see, but i think it's because i fail to express what exactly i want. You see. What i want is to be able to write this: `\chapter*{Forord} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Forord}`, and then get it to look identical to the chapters that i have written as just `\chapter{}`. With regards to the headline.

Comment: @MikkelMiqlliotLehmann I am sorry, but I thought this was, what my first solution did? Can you show some sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: Okay, so the `\chapter` environment consists of 3 things. 1. the "Chapter" 2. the number (1,2,3 etc.). and 3. the "Name" in your example above, the name is "This has formatting". 

What we have done, is given the chapter and number part a new style. So that the Chapter and number is red. 

When i write `\chapter*(SOMETHING)` then this part is all black, and regular. when you use the `\chapter*(SOMETHING)` command, the chapter and number part is gone. What i want is that when i write  `\chapter*(SOMETHING)` i want it to be the same style as the chapter and number part from the first example.

Comment: But i dont want it to show the "Chapter" and the "number" i just want the chapter text to be the same style as the "Chapter" and "number", can you follow me? This is because i have a lot of chapters, for example: Chapter 1 (Processing) , Chapter 2 (Industrializing) and so forth, but i also have some chapters name "Conclusion" etc. Which i want to be the same red style, but i dont want them to have the "Chapter x" part.

Comment: @MikkelMiqlliotLehmann Another guess, see my edit. Is this the result you intent?

Comment: YES! Very nice, you have been such a big help, i cannot thank you enough! :-)